# How to write a multi-objective function in gurobi python

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I'm working on a multi-objective optimization problem using Gurobi with Python.

Here is part of my code that shows how I define the objective function:

```
model.setObjective( quicksum(w[k]*R[k]*3 for k in stations)
                   +quicksum(cost[l]*z[l,k] for l in L for k in stations),
                   GRB.MINIMIZE )
```

I want multiple objectives. First I want to optimize the first summand, then the second.

Answer (score 3):

You can define multiple objectives in a hierarchical way. Here is how you would do this:

```
model.setObjectiveN(quicksum(w[k]*R[k]*3 for k in stations), 0, 1)
model.setOjbectiveN(quicksum(cost[l]*z[l,k] for l in L for k in stations), 1, 0)
```

This code defines two hierarchical objectives. The first argument is the expression (i.e., the summands in your original code), the second argument is the index of the objective, the third argument defines the priority. (Higher priority means this objective will be solved first.) See [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_setobjectiven.html) for more information about setObjectiveN.

By default, Gurobi will minimize, but you can also make this explicit:

```
model.ModelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE
```

When you call optimize, Gurobi will solve the model with the first objective, then add a constraint that ensures that the objective value of this constraint will not degrade and then solve the model for the second objective.

You can also allow a certain amount of degradation by defining (absolute and/or relative) tolerances.
[Here is more information about working with multiple objectives in Gurobi.](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/working_with_multiple_obje.html)

Comment: 1-Does this expression minimize the value of the objective function by default without mentioning it in the code?.                                                                                                      2- How can I print the output value of the variables for the first objective only and then the final value for both objectives?                                                                                                    3- Thank you so much for your help @Silke Horn

Comment: Yes, minimizing is the default. Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you have any idea if i could print the values of the decision variables for the first objective only ?, as i'm working also on algorithm for the same model so i want to understand how it works in details